# Can't set a local variable in python directly through `locals()`

Tags: python, namespaces

I'll keep this one short and simple. Why does the following behaviour occur?

```
>>> globals()['x'] = 5
>>> x
5
>>> def f():
...    locals()['y'] = 7
...    y
...
>>> f()
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<pyshell#32>", line 1, in <module>
    f()
  File "<pyshell#31>", line 3, in f
    y
NameError: name 'y' is not defined
```

Here's an example of where this might be used:

```
import opcode
def foo():
    locals().update(opcode.opmap)
    #do stuff
```

Comment: I'm very curious why you want to do it this way instead of `y = 7`.

Comment: I don't think I would ever use this, I was just experimenting.

Comment: @TheSoundDefense I updated the question to include a scenario in which it might be useful.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[The documentation for locals() includes](https://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html#locals):

> **Note:** The contents of this dictionary should not be modified; changes may not affect the values of local and free variables used by the interpreter.

Comment: Well that was fast, thanks!

Comment: ... and the reason you can't modify `locals()` is that the Python interpreter optimizes access to local variables at compile time; they aren't stored in a dictionary the way globals are.